# Step in proof of Ito isometry

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

### Question

I am following the course [advanced stochastic processes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec15.pdf) online but I'm struggling with an equality in the proof of Ito iseometry of theorem 1. On the third line of page 3 it is used that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{t_j}^2 \mathbb{E}[(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j})^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_j}]] = \mathbb{E}[X_{t_j}^2 (t_{j+1} -t_j)].
$$
where $X_t$ is a simple process and $(B_t)_t$ a Brownian motion, both adopted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_t$. I'm pretty sure this step isn't very hard to show but I can't figure it out.

### Side Question

I have a mathematical background and I'm looking at this theory to tackle inventory theory problems in a mathematical way, if you have some more interesting further references this could also be interesting. I'm thinking about [Applied Probability and Queues](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97236)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the settings of a brownian motion $(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j})$ is independent of $F_{t_j}$ so for every measurable function is holds $$E[f(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_j}] = E[f(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j})]$$

Taking $f(x) = x^2$ and consider that $(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t_{j+1} - t_j)$ we get

$$E[(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j})^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_j}] = E[(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j})^2] = t_{j+1} - t_j$$

Comment: Ok, yes forgot about using the idependant increments (quite silly of me). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the definition of the Brownian motion:

1. Independent increments
2. Increments over interval $\Delta t$ are distributed according to $N(0,\Delta t)$

Thus, 
$$E[(B_{t_j+1}−B_{t_j})^2∣F_{t_j}] = E[(B_{t_j+1}−B_{t_j})^2]=t_{j+1}-t_{j}$$